# Is there a bigger cumulative graph than the one on the profile?

Tags: support, reputation-graph

On my Stack Overflow profile I can see the following graph:

[image]

However, if I click it, I can see just a "reward-per-day" chart, and not a cumulative one like this... are there ways to have a bigger version of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The graph in your network profile is a bit bigger. You can find it at https://stackexchange.com/users/current/?tab=reputation

[image: screenshot of the network reputation graph of the OP]

Do note, this graph will only show sites where you have at least 200 reputation points.